# Inbuilt cropping tool for image in file picker for WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, crop, win-universal-app, filepicker

Is there any option to crop after choosing image using filepicker? In WP8, photochoser task had a similar option, is there any alternative to that for WP8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file picker returns the file and doesn't do any direct manipulations. You can crop when you read the file in by passing a [BitmapTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.aspx) with cropping information into your [BitmapDecoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.aspx).[GetPixelDataAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br226193.aspx) call. The [How to crop bitmap in a Windows Store app (C#)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7) sample demonstrates this - it targets Windows Store apps rather than Windows Phone, but the cropping code will be the same for both Windows Runtime targets.

There are also several external libraries which can provide cropping behaviour, such as the [Lumia Imaging SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/lumia) and [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/))

If you want to do this visually you'll need to provide your own UI for that. The [How to crop bitmap in a Windows Store app (C#)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7) sample demonstrates this as well, but will need some changes to fit a phone's screen.

Comment: used to the cropping sample to build one for phone. Thanks :)

Comment: hi, could you tell me how did you use the build-in crop tool? Thanks

Comment: There is no built-in crop tool apps can call. The linked sample demonstrates one way to implement your own.